# How can I programmatically configure a log4j 2.5 RollingRandomAccessFileAppender to limit files without renaming?

Tags: java, log4j2

I have thousands of processes creating logs using log4j2 and renaming all of the files on every rollover is not acceptable due to the burden it places on the filesystem.

Currently I have the following code to create the Appender:

```
PathCondition[] pathConditions = new PathCondition[1];
pathConditions[0] = IfAccumulatedFileCount.createFileCountCondition(10);

DeleteAction deleteAction = DeleteAction.createDeleteAction(basePath, true, 1, true, null, pathConditions, null, config);
Action[] actions = new Action[1];
actions[0] = deleteAction;

String filename = "file";
String filePattern = fileName + "_%i.log";
RollingRandomAccessFileAppender appender = RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.createAppender(
      fileName,
      filePattern,
      "false", // append
      "RollingRandomAccessFileAppender", // name
      "true", // immediateFlush
      "8192", // bufferSizeStr
      SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(Long.valueOf(maxFileSizeInMB*1024*1024).toString()),
      DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy(Integer.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE).toString(), "1", "max", null, actions, true, config),
      getLayout(),
      null, // filter
      "true", // ignore exceptions (they get logged)
      "false", // advertise
      "", // advertiseURI
      config);
```

But when I run it my process gets murdered by the OS as it is spamming the filesystem trying to stat every file between 1 and Integer.MAX_VALUE which came as quite a shock (seems like a defect, after finding one non-existent file there is no reason to look for subsequent numbers), from strace -f:

```
...
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412901.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412901.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412900.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412900.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412899.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412899.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412898.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412898.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412897.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412897.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412896.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412896.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412895.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412895.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412894.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412894.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412893.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412893.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412892.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412892.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 18155] stat("file_2147412891.log", 0x2b74134f96d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
```

Stack trace in the JVM while this is happening:

```
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(UnixFileSystem.java:242)
at java.io.File.exists(File.java:819)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.purgeAscending(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:305)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:279)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy.rollover(DefaultRolloverStrategy.java:506)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover(RollingFileManager.java:196)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.rollover(RollingFileManager.java:124)
- locked <0x00000005c0196238> (a org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.checkRollover(RollingFileManager.java:119)
- locked <0x00000005c0196238> (a org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingRandomAccessFileManager)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.append(RollingRandomAccessFileAppender.java:89)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:152)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:125)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:116)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:390)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:378)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:362)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:352)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:147)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1011)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:988)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.log(AbstractLogger.java:866)
```

I was trying to do this to prevent file renaming so that I could somehow use the DeleteAction to keep the number of files down while still letting them roll to arbitrarily high numbers.

Comment: Your use case is a good illustration of the need for a more modular rollover strategy: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1198

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation on the DefaultRolloverStrategy you will see that it describes this behavior. It is really designed for you to keep a fairly small, fixed number of files, not an arbitrary number.

For what you are trying to do I would think adding a fileIndex value of something like "unlimited" or none that would not try to purge the files at all and instead rely on your DeleteAction configuration would make sense. I would suggest you create a jira issue for this. If you can provide the patch that would even be better.

Update: As of version 2.8 Log4j no longer tries to look for all the files between the min and max and only looks at the files that are actually on disk. This should help eliminate the problem you were having. Also, in the same release a new feature was added to allow you to write directly to the rolled over file so no renames need to take place at all.